# Dash App Refresh Underlying Pandas Dataframe hourly

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a Dash App dashboard where the graphs are created from a Pandas Dataframe. The Dataframe is currently a global variable outside any callback/ function. The reason why it is outside is because it uses pyathena to query AWS Athena for data which takes a minute. What I need is to have the app refresh as a whole periodically so the Dataframe data can refresh, or have just the Dataframe part of the code refresh so the App can stay online. Either one works for me. I have looked into dcc.Interval() as well as scheduling, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a `dcc.Interval` component as part of a [long callback](https://dash.plotly.com/long-callbacks). Then you can update the dataframe inside the callback, but without worrying about timing out.

Comment: I have not looked into long callbacks, my issue with callbacks was I did not know what the Output() would be, the input is easy but could not figure that out.

Comment: The output is probably going to be the `figure` prop of your `dcc.Graph` component.